# Problemas con la conexion a mysql con java

Tags: java, mysql

Mi problema es que mi aplicación de java genera demasiadas conexiones sin control. En primera instancias pensé que era porque no estaba cerrando las conexiones correctamente, pero el problema no se soluciona. Alguna otra opción para poder cerrar esas conexiones sin control?

En este fragmento esta el codigo de conexion(tanto el metodo de conexion como el metodo de desconexion)

```js
public Connection MySQLConnection(String user, String pass, String db_name)  {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + db_name, user, pass);
            System.out.println("Conectado");
//            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha iniciado la conexión con el servidor de forma exitosa");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
        }
        return conexion;
    }
    public  void closeConnection() {
        try {
            conexion.close();
//            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha finalizado la conexión con el servidor");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Y este es el codigo de un ejemplo en donde realizo la conexion y desconexion de la base de datos para realizar una operacion para cargar un combobox.

```js
public void comboboxar(JComboBox<String> combo){
        con =new conexion();
        Connection c=con.MySQLConnection("root","", "emcisa");
        try {
            
            Statement st3=c.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs2=st3.executeQuery("SELECT id_productos FROM productos WHERE baja=0");
            combo.removeAllItems();
            while(rs2.next()){
                combo.addItem(rs2.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }finally {
            con.closeConnection();
        }
```

Comment: puedes colocar tu código para ayudarte

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. En la pregunta falta mucha información: qué arquitectura usas (¿gestionas directamente las conexiones o usas un pool?¿aplicación desktop o servidor de aplicaciones?), cuál es el comportamiento notado (¿cuántas conexiones se abren?¿es continuo o se para?) y muchas cosas más...

Comment: Gestiono directamente las conexiones y lo que estoy haciendo es una aplicacion de escritorio. El programa con el cual veo las tablas de mysql es wampserver. La cantidad de conexiones que se abren son mas de 50 y es continuo. Pienso que tenga algo que ver con el server porque cuando me fije en la consola de mysql y escribi el comando show status like 'Threads%' me aparecio que tengo mas de 8000 Threads creados, no se si esto tendra algo que ver. utilizo un conector llamado mysqlconector que es un jar

Comment: Sin ver tu código no podemos precisar más allá de ... **usa un pool de conexiones**

Comment: Posiblemente tengas esta función en un ciclo, es por eso

Comment: quien asegura que siempre que abris una conexion, la estes cerrando?

Comment: José, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Para esta y futuras preguntas ten en cuenta que aquí [un fragmento de código en texto vale más que mil imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2990/29967). Por favor, considera [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/140833/edit) cambiando la imagen por el texto del código. Será más fácil de analizar y revisar y contribuirá a una solución más óptima de tu problema. Gracias.

Comment: Si anteriormente tu programa creaba conexiones sin control y posteriormente corregiste eso, ten en cuenta que los `8000` o más hilos seguirán abiertos mientras no reinicies el equipo o el servidor de la BD. Tienes que revisar todas las partes del código donde usas conexiones y asegurarte de que las cierras posteriormente... pero no sólo la conexión en sí, también los `ResultSet`, los `PreparedStatement` y todo lo que tenga que ver con la base de datos. También tienes que revisar que el código esté optimizado, que no crea conexiones en bucles y cosas de ese tipo.

Comment: Donde podria reiniciar el servidor de la base de datos? Ya que si bien estuve buscando como hacerlo, no encontre como.

Comment: Sigo con el problema. ya cerre todas aquellas operaciones resultset o preparedstatment de mi progama como asi las conexiones y nada;

Comment: Lo mejor que puedes hacer, como ya te comentó @PabloLozano, la mejor alternativa para evitar este tipo de problemas es utilizar un pool de conexiones. Te dejo [este artículo](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Pool_de_conexiones) que explica muy bien como comenzar a utilizar estas.

Comment: Esta pregunta podria ayudarte bastante https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/215888/problema-cuando-cierro-mi-conexi%C3%B3n-de-mysql-en-java/215965#215965

Answer (score 1):

Cuando abres una conexión a una DB de esa forma el workaround para culminar la conexion es cerrando el resultset, luego el statement, y al final la conexion para mantenerlo lo mas limpio posible, solo estas cerrando la conexión y estas dejando en el ejecución los dos ultimos.

```
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try{
//.....
}catch(exception e){
//....
}finally{
    try { rs.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* ignored */ }
    try { ps.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* ignored */ }
    try { conn.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* ignored */ }
}
```

Apache tiene una utilidad para resumir este proceso:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/

Tambien te recomiendo que uses herramientas como jdbcTemplate, o ORMs como JPA.