# Problema cuando cierro mi conexión de MySQL en Java

Tags: java, mysql, mysqlconnector

Tengo mi clase **MySQLConnection** donde hago mi conexión con el driver, etc. En la clase **TrailerBox** llamo el método estático para obtener conexión y lo utilizo para realizar una consulta. Se supone que funciona "correctamente", pero cuando intento realizar mas de 151 constructores de mi clase (consultas a la db), me aparece el siguiente error:

> *Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"*

Estas son mis clases:
**MySQLConnection.java**

```
package models;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MySQLConnection {

//mysql parameters
private static final String SERVER = "localhost";
private static final String DATABASE = "logistics";
private static final String USER = "root";
private static final String PASSWORD = "";

//get connection
public static Connection getConnection() {
    //connection 
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        //connection string 
        String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://" + SERVER + "/" + DATABASE + "?user=" + USER + "&serverTimezone=UTC";
        //add password to connection string if needed
        if (PASSWORD != "") {
            connectionString += "&password=" + PASSWORD;
        }
        //MySQL Java Drivers
        //Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        //MySQL connection
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

    }
    return connection;
}
```

}

Y este es el constructor donde utilizo el metodo:

```
public static ArrayList<TrailerBox> getAll() {
    ArrayList<TrailerBox> list = new ArrayList<>();
    PreparedStatement command;
    ResultSet result;
    String query = "select s.id, s.description, s.ipAddress from trailerboxes as s order by s.id";
    try {
        //prepare statement
        command = MySQLConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        //execute query
        result = command.executeQuery();
        //read rows
        while (result.next()) {
            //read fields
            int id = result.getInt("id");
            String description = result.getString("description");
            String ipAddress = result.getString("ipAddress");
            //add new order to list
            list.add(new TrailerBox(id, description, ipAddress));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    //return list
    return list;
}
```

Intente agregando un `finally` a mi try-catch de la conexión:

```
} finally {
    if (connection != null) {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException ignore) {
        }
    }
}
```

Pero me arroja este mensaje:

> *No operations allowed after connection closed.*

De antemano, les agradezco su ayuda, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El Problema quizás radica en tu clase de conexión,al llamar al constructor de la clase estas abriendo una nueva conexión con cada instancia,debes de tratar de Seguir siempre el Patrón de singleton,más abajo de Comparto una clase de Conexión lista para usarse,la misma no permite instanciar el objeto.y solo abre la conexión una sola vez.

```
 package Genericos;

 import Preferencias.Preferencias;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ConexionDB {
private static ConexionDB INSTANCE = null;
private static Connection dbcon;
private String host;
private String db;
private String user;
private String pass;

private static String msg;

public static enum TR {INICIAR, FINALIZAR, CANCELAR};

private ConexionDB() {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        if(procesar() == false){
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
    }
}

public static Connection getDBcon() {
    return dbcon;
}

public static ConexionDB getInstancia() {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = new ConexionDB();
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}

private boolean procesar(){
    if(datosTxt() == false){
        host = Preferencias.GET_IP();
        pass = Preferencias.GET_BD_PASS();
        db = Preferencias.GET_DB_NAME();
        user = Preferencias.GET_BD_USER();
    }
    return conectar();
}

private boolean datosTxt(){
    return false;
}

private boolean conectar(){
    String sCon = "jdbc:mysql://"+ host +"/"+ db;
    try{
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

       dbcon = DriverManager.getConnection(sCon, user, pass);
       System.err.println("Parametros de Conexion....");
       System.err.println("host:"+host);
       System.err.println("db:"+db);
       System.err.println("user:"+user);
       System.err.println("pass:"+pass);
       if (dbcon != null) {
           msg = "Se conectó correctamente a la base de datos.";
           System.out.println(msg);
           return true;
       }else{
           msg = "Error al conectar a la base de datos.";

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error al conectarse a la base de datos");

           return false;
       }
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
        msg = "Error driver! "+ e.getMessage();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error Al conectarse con el Sevidor:"+e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}

public static void cerrar(){
    try{
        dbcon.close();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR AL TERMINAR LA CONEXION");
    }
}

public static void Transaccion(TR accion){
    try {
        switch(accion){
            case INICIAR:
                dbcon.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
                dbcon.setAutoCommit(false); 
                break;
            case FINALIZAR:     
                dbcon.commit();
                dbcon.setAutoCommit(true); 
                break;
            case CANCELAR:
                dbcon.rollback();
                dbcon.setAutoCommit(true); 
                break;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    msg = "Error al establecer estado de transacciones.";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error al establecer estado de transacciones.:"+ex.getMessage());

    }
}

}
```

Un ejemplo para el uso de la clase sería.

```
public class AccesoCTR {
private final Acceso acceso;
private PreparedStatement pst;
private ResultSet rst;
private String Sql;

public AccesoCTR(Acceso accesovm) {
  /*Abrimos la conexion en el Contructor de la clase que necesitamos usar*/
    ConexionDB.getInstancia();
}

/*Ejemplo de Select con la clase*/

 public boolean ValidarUsuarios(){
      try {

         Sql ="SELECT cod_usuario, usuario, cod_perfil,cod_funcionario FROM usuarios 
             \n" +
             "WHERE estado and usuario=? and clave=?";
        pst=ConexionDB.getDBcon().prepareStatement(Sql);
        pst.setString(1, acceso.txtusuario.getText().trim());
        pst.setString(2, acceso.txtclave.getText().trim());
        rst=pst.executeQuery();
        if (rst.next()) {
            Principal.permiso=rst.getInt("cod_perfil");
            VentaCTR.funcionario=rst.getInt("cod_funcionario");

            return true;
        }
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error Al  iniciar Sesion " +ex);
        return false;
      }

      return false;
  }
```

La clase **ConexionDB** funciona correctamente te recomiendo que lo uses.!

Comment: Me funcionó, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Saludos aquí te dejo un ejemplo simple y funcional alrgoritmo para gestión de biblioteca del 2013. Puedes actualizar el mismo según tus requerimientos.

```
public Object[] verificacion(String cedula, PasswordField clave){
    boolean existe = false;
   Connection con = new Conexion_bd().getConexion();      
   Statement sentencia = null;
   ResultSet resultado = null; 
   String ced=null, usua=null, tipo=null;

    try {             

          sentencia = con.createStatement();
          resultado = sentencia.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM biblioteca.autenticacion WHERE cedula='"+cedula+"' AND clave='"+encriptar.conversor(clave.getText(), "SHA-512")+"';");

          if(resultado.next()){
              existe = true;
              ced = resultado.getString("cedula");
              usua = resultado.getString("usuario");
              tipo = resultado.getString("tipo");

              personal = ced+" - "+usua;//variable estatica global

          }else{
              existe = false;                  
          }

         sentencia.close();
         resultado.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        new Mensajes().error("ERROR: \n"+ex.getMessage());
        Logger.getLogger(Registro_Autenticacion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }finally{
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            new Mensajes().error("ERROR: \n"+ex.getMessage());
            Logger.getLogger(Registro_Autenticacion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
    return new Object[]{existe,ced,usua,tipo};
}
```